# Docker node app won't bind with host

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have an app composed of a mysql db, and node app. I wrote a docker-compose file that creates and exposes a mysql db and the node app. I managed to do this by copying all source files of the app to the container and running the app, but I can't have the node app react to file changes on my host. I did add a volumes entry on the docker-compose.yml but the app doesn't react to it.

My folder structure on the host is:

[image]

The web-client is a React front-end that is not involved yet in this (I'm taking it one step at a time).

The folder server has the node app and a Dockerfile.

server/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8

RUN apt-get -q update && apt-get -qy install netcat

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

RUN ls -l
RUN npm install

RUN chmod +x ./wait-for.sh
CMD sh -c './wait-for.sh mysql-db:3306 -- npm start'

EXPOSE 5000
```

server/.dockerignore:

```
node_modules
npm-debug.log
*Dockerfile*
*docker-compose*
```

./docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: assinaai
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: assinaai
      MYSQL_DATABASE: assinaai
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - "3306"
    networks:
      - my-network

  node-app:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    expose:
      - "5000"
    volumes:
      - "./server:/usr/src/app"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: [Mount relative path does not work with volumes in docker compose file](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5108)

Comment: Thanks @alvits, but isn't this exactly what the docker-compose.yml on this page does? https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this sample project](https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults) on Github I was able to accomplish what I wanted. Look into the docker-compose.yml for the correct syntax on binding mounts.